# PHP htaccess error while passing GET variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got an issue when try to access GET variable in PHP while using .htaccess file to rewrite the url in SEO friendly style.

Using an URL like  www.example.com/blog/index.php?article=foo-bar I can load correctly the page, but when I use something like www.example.com/blog/article/foo-bar/ I got a redirect to the index page.

Here is my .htaccess file (note that I'm using a rule to remove the index.php in the URL)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /blog/index.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /blog/index.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^adm/$ /blog/index.php?page=admin [QSA,L]
```

As replied to another post an user post me this correction, but produces an error 500, I don't got any replies about the 500 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L] #This cause the error 500
RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /blog/index.php?article=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /blog/index.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^adm/$ /blog/index.php?page=admin [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php?/$1 [L] # This too cause an error 500 in this position
```

By the way when i click a link refered to a category, instead of restrict only to an article in selected category i got the full list of article like the homepage.

Thanks, for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^article/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?article=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?category=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^adm/?$ /blog/index.php?page=admin [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you check Apache error.log and see what the error is? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: my error.log located in var/logs/apache2 is blank, i've tried to set the loglevel to info in apache config but still blank

Comment: In the conf file i got this line ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log I'm using Cloud9 so maybe the vfs is configured to store these log in other path?

Comment: Ok no 500 errors, but still not working, every link send me to the home. You can try here http://aem-new-andreaem-dev.c9users.io/blog/

Comment: Is your .htaccess located inside `blog` folder? If yes can you try my updated rules

Comment: excuse me for reopening the question, i've moved the blog in a subdomain of my website. http://blog.andreaem.com/ and now the .htaccess still not working another time, i've make a correction removing /blog/ from the RewriteRule leaving only eg. /index.php?foo=$1, but now I got the 500 error.

Comment: Does `index.php` exist in site root? Difficult to say without error.log what is causing 500.

Comment: Yes index.php still exist, is a virtualhost in an ubuntu server, since i've changed host now i got the error.log file, the last line i see on the log is: [Tue Jun 14 20:03:24.019623 2016] [:error] [pid 20790] [client IP.IP.IP.IP:53008] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: article in /var/www/html/blog.andreaem.com/index.php on line 7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114676/discussion-between-anubhava-and-andreaem).

Answer (score 3):

You need to test with OR:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```